# How to detect snort alerts with Java?

Tags: java, snort

Is there any Java API or Class that can be used in a Java code allowing to detect in real time Snort alerts without using Snort log files ? In other words, does Snort can send alerts which can be recieved by a server process rather than recording them in a log file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the syslog forwarding options.

Answer (score 0):

### On Unix

If you are on Unix you can use unix-sockets to send the snort alert to. Then you can either use the Java Native Interface (JNI) to create your own api for unix sockets in java. Or use a preexisting one like [junixsocket](https://github.com/kohlschutter/junixsocket).

Of course you also need to read the data snort sent to you. This would efficiently also be done with the JNI.

But in the end the whole process of sending data from c-structs in a c program to a java client is never really trivial.